# Raspberry Pi as a web server security

Tags: python, security, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm currently making a small hobby project where I use a Raspberry Pi Zero to control a set of RGB LED's.

I've got a basic python app so far that is built on Flask that allows me to set up a web server so that the LED colours can be set remotely.

My main concern is that I'm self-taught as far as programming goes and I don't know squat about security.

The plan is essentially to be sending any port 80 traffic to the raspberry pi on my home network and give friends my IP. I may eventually get a domain name to simplify things.

Should I have any security concerns when I set this up live full-time? I don't know if it's possible to access my private network via the raspberry pi or if I'm just being paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting your Raspberry PI on separate `vlan` and put your home devices on another `vlan`. Please note you need a router which supports `vlan` and configure it in a way that the both vlans cant talk to each other

Also, try using `HTTPS` for your webserver and don't run the webserver process as `root` user. If you want to go more crazy you can put a firewall.

These are generic suggestions for hardening the security for any web app.

Answer (score 0):

If your experimenting and learning... might be a great opportunity to try out something called wire-guard, if you don't have the network equipment to support vlans.

https://engineerworkshop.com/blog/how-to-set-up-wireguard-on-a-raspberry-pi/

You and your friends can directly connect to the pi, add some appropriate  iptables firewall, and you can restrict them just to that machine.

If you want learn more about secure coding, there are tons of resources. Maybe even get you and your friends 'to capture the pi' .... and learn from each other!

What ever you do , keeping hacking away, and keep having fun....